# How to not cache server worker client

Tags: caching, client, message, service-worker

I've a webpage that sends a message to a service worker script. To be able to do this, the webpage needs to be a client of the server worker script. 
There are different methods to do this, but as far as I know all methods results in that client webpages are cached in the service worker.

I was wondering if it's possible that a webpage can send messages to a server worker script, withouth it having to be cached to the server worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure—there's no requirement that a service worker cache anything at all, or even that a service worker implement a `fetch` handler and intercept network requests. You could create a service worker that just has a `message` handler that listens for incoming messages from the pages it controls:

```
// service-worker.js:
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  // Do something with event.data
});
```

But if you're just using a service worker to listen for messages, and not intercept network requests, I wonder whether an alternative like a [`SharedWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) or just a plain-vanilla [`Worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) would be a better alternative?